# Феячити - український чи російський неологізм?

Tags: неологізми

Натрапила у Фейсбуку на таку фразу: "Ви знаєте, що трапляється, коли наші Книжкові феї дуже засмучуються? Вони **феячать**!"

Цитату взято із групи [Фабула](https://www.facebook.com/Fabulabook/?hc_ref=ARR1wBV-vu97VRTjbnczf00dqnvyM04lF4a91yOVwQIqgJueZQfziakYqPsHzyEZsEA&fref=nf).

Одразу ж пишу сюди. Перегортала деякі джерела, і СУМ, інші тлумачні словники,а також і в російських словниках онлайн передивлялася, ніде не згадано такого неологізму. Подається лише значення лексеми "фея":

*Фея - у міфології деяких західноєвропейських народів — істота жіночої статі (звичайно доброзичлива), здатна творити чудеса; чарівниця.*

*перен. Про жінку, яка чарує своєю грацією, красою і т. ін., яка робить добро, приносить щастя тощо.*

Так, виходячи зі самої семантики "фея", розумію, що слід перекласти, як "чарують", але все ж ніде слова у мною переглянутих словниках (вибачте за тавтологію)  як такого не зафіксовано. Коли вводжу російською цей неологізм, то, як вже згадувала, визначення нема, проте пошук видає аж 11 200 результатів із використання поданого слова; коли ж українською, то "відправляє" до російської версії. Тоді питання: а чи нормативно його вживати? Випадково це не калька з російської тоді? Чи це український, чи російський неологізм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Феячити - робити з власної волі щось хороше, незвичайне (таке визначення я знайшов на цьому російському [форумі](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1879103-chto-znachit-fejachit.html)).

Досить складно дати точну відповідь коли з'явився цей неологізм і чи він спершу з'явився в російській чи українській мовах.

Що ми маємо? Перша частина слова - це запозичене з англійської мови "фея", а також друга частина "-чити". Гадаю, що воно могло виникнути і в нашій мові, щось на кшталт слів "[пиячити](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyjachyty)", "[вирячити](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyrjachuvaty)" тощо. Але таким самим чином воно могло з'явитися і в російській мові, тому складно сказати калька це чи ні.